Floating-point adder/subtractor - Bound check error
I'm writing code for a floating-point adder/subtractor. I had multiple errors so I am debugging. At this point, when attempting to simulate, I get the error below the code:
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity fp_sum_subs is
    generic (
        NE: natural := 8;
        NF: natural := 23
    );
    port (
        rst:      in std_logic;
        clk:      in std_logic;
        sum_subs: in std_logic;
        x:   in std_logic_vector(NF+NE downto 0);
        y:   in std_logic_vector(NF+NE downto 0);
        z:   out std_logic_vector(NF+NE downto 0);

        mx_p :   out unsigned(NF downto 0);
        my_p :   out unsigned(NF downto 0);

        sx :             out std_logic;
        fx :             out std_logic_vector(NF-1 downto 0);
        ex :             out unsigned(NE-1 downto 0);

        sy :             out std_logic;
        fy :             out std_logic_vector(NF-1 downto 0);
        ey :             out unsigned(NE-1 downto 0);

        mx:              out unsigned(NF downto 0);
        my:              out unsigned(NF downto 0)
    );
end fp_sum_subs;

architecture behavioral of fp_sum_subs is
    constant EXC : signed(NE+1 downto 0) := to_signed((2**(NE-1)) - 1, NE+2);
    signal x_reg :          std_logic_vector(NF+NE downto 0);
    signal y_reg :          std_logic_vector(NF+NE downto 0);
    signal sum_subs_reg:    std_logic;
    -- signal sx :             std_logic;
    -- signal fx :             std_logic_vector(NF-1 downto 0);
    -- signal ex :             unsigned(NE-1 downto 0);
    signal ex_ext :         signed(NE downto 0);
    -- signal sy :             std_logic;
    -- signal fy :             std_logic_vector(NF-1 downto 0);
    -- signal ey :             unsigned(NE-1 downto 0);
    signal ey_ext :         signed(NE downto 0);
    signal exp_diff:        signed(NE downto 0);
    signal abs_exp_diff :   unsigned(NE downto 0);
    -- signal mx :             unsigned(NF downto 0);
    -- signal my :             unsigned(NF downto 0);
    signal mx_p_nt_a:       signed(2**NE downto 0);
    signal my_p_t_a:        signed(2**NE downto 0);

    -- signal mx_p :             unsigned(NF downto 0);
    -- signal my_p :             unsigned(NF downto 0);

begin

    process(clk, rst)
    begin
        if rst = '1' then
            x_reg <= (others => '0');
            y_reg <= (others => '0');
            sum_subs_reg <= '0';
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            x_reg <= x;
            y_reg <= y;
            sum_subs_reg <= sum_subs;
        end if;
    end process;

    sx <= x_reg(NF+NE);
    fx <= x_reg(NF-1 downto 0);
    ex <= unsigned(x_reg(NF+NE-1 downto NF));

    sy <= y_reg(NF+NE);
    fy <= y_reg(NF-1 downto 0);
    ey <= unsigned(y_reg(NF+NE-1 downto NF));

    ex_ext <= signed('0' & std_logic_vector(ex));
    ey_ext <= signed('0' & std_logic_vector(ey));

    exp_diff <= ex_ext - ey_ext;

    process(all) begin
        if exp_diff(NE) = '1' then
            abs_exp_diff <= unsigned(not(std_logic_vector(exp_diff))) + 1;
        else
            abs_exp_diff <= unsigned(exp_diff);
        end if;
    end process;

    mx <= unsigned('1' & fx);
    my <= unsigned('1' & fy);

    mx_p <= mx when exp_diff(NE) = '0' else my;

    my_p <= my when exp_diff(NE) = '0' else mx;

    -- -- TODO bound check error
    mx_p_nt_a   <=      signed(
                         std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(0, 2**NE - 1 - NF - abs_exp_diff)) &
                         std_logic_vector(mx_p)                                          &
                         std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(0, abs_exp_diff))
                         );
     my_p_t_a    <=      signed(
                         std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(0, 2**NE - 1 - NF))                &
                         std_logic_vector(my_p)
                         );

end architecture behavioral;

This is the error and I don't understand what's wrong:
$ make
ghdl -a --std=08 ../../rtl/fp_sum_subs.vhd
ghdl -a --std=08 ../../tb/tb.vhd
ghdl -e --std=08 tb
ghdl -r --std=08 tb --wave=waves.ghw
ghdl:error: bound check failure at ../../rtl/fp_sum_subs.vhd:101
ghdl:error: simulation failed
make: *** [Makefile:35: tb.out] Error 1

I tried changing the size of mx_p_nt_a and my_p_t_a by adding one more bit and also with one less bit and I still get the same error.
The testbench I'm using is:
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use std.textio.all;

entity tb is
end tb;

architecture sim of tb is
    constant CLK_PERIOD : time := 10 ns; -- Adjusted for a realistic clock period
    constant TEST_TIME : time := 1000 ns;

   -- Constants for bit widths
    constant NF : natural := 21; -- Example value for fraction width
    constant NE : natural := 7; -- Example value for exponent width

    signal clk, rst : std_logic := '0';
    signal sum_subs : std_logic := '1';
    signal x, y, z, z_expected : std_logic_vector(NF+NE downto 0); -- Adjusted to NE+NF downto 0
    signal mx_p, my_p: unsigned(NF downto 0); 
    signal sx, sy: std_logic;
    signal fx, fy: std_logic_vector(NF-1 downto 0);
    signal ex, ey: unsigned(NE-1 downto 0);
    signal mx, my: unsigned(NF downto 0);

    -- File variables

begin
    -- Instantiate the fp_sum_subs entity (assuming unchanged)
    u_fp_sum_subs: entity work.fp_sum_subs
        generic map (
            NE => NE,
            NF => NF
        )
        port map (
            rst => rst,
            clk => clk,
            sum_subs => sum_subs,
            x => x,
            y => y,
            z => z,
            sx => sx,
            sy => sy,
            fx => fx,
            fy => fy,
            ex => ex,
            ey => ey,
            mx => mx,
            my => my,
            mx_p => mx_p,
            my_p => my_p
        );

    -- Clock process (assuming unchanged)
    clk_process : process
    begin
        while now < TEST_TIME loop
            clk <= '0';
            wait for CLK_PERIOD / 2;
            clk <= '1';
            wait for CLK_PERIOD / 2;
        end loop;
        wait;
    end process clk_process;

    -- Reset process (assuming unchanged)
    reset_process : process
    begin
        rst <= '1'; -- Assert reset
        wait for CLK_PERIOD * 2; -- Hold reset for 2 clock cycles
        rst <= '0'; -- De-assert reset
        wait;
    end process reset_process;

    -- Stimulus process
    stimulus_process : process
        variable temp_x, temp_y, temp_z : integer;
        variable test_line : line;
        file test_file : text;
    begin
        wait for CLK_PERIOD * 4;

        -- Open the test vector file
        file_open(test_file, "../../tb/fsub_" & integer'image(NF) & "_" & integer'image(NE) & ".txt", read_mode);

        -- Read and ignore header
        readline(test_file, test_line);

        -- Read test vectors and apply them
        while not endfile(test_file) loop
            readline(test_file, test_line);
            read(test_line, temp_x);
            read(test_line, temp_y);
            read(test_line, temp_z);
            x <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(temp_x, x'length));
            y <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(temp_y, y'length));
            z_expected <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(temp_z, z_expected'length));
            wait for CLK_PERIOD; -- Adjust delay as needed
        end loop;

        -- Close file after reading
        file_close(test_file);

        wait;
    end process stimulus_process;

end sim;


And the file I'm using looks like:
FSUB FE_TOWARDZERO 29
153912492 161779602 430032711 
60030156 218196266 486631721 
331795566 408787674 140352217 
43489586 175063368 443498823 
203518490 71709244 203518489 
35483362 361248288 92812832 
138550966 398413710 138680626 
91399222 129347438 397782881 
439634942 113109494 439634942 
173250896 402405974 173250903 
231970888 480703418 231975873 
348301244 57008598 348302456 
424260674 246752040 515187496 
68944462 27445968 68944457 
372880822 126693796 395131098 
227578720 495471396 229404482 
495251808 248863322 517301142 
147726344 409148644 148013988 
114339760 495939336 227503880 
281439638 160295940 428731396 
481666598 68561124 481666598 
238515140 476229080 238515278


If you were to supply a [mcve] including a testbench with the stimuli being applied when the error occurred (which is al not provided here) the issue could be duplicated. There's also an equivalent process statement for a concurrent assignment statement wherein report statements preceding the signal assignment can be used to evaluate expressions, in this case to determine length of the concatenated waveform.

You have abs_exp_diff in the length parameter of the to unsigned function. This is an unsigned value and the function expects only an natural.

This is -2008. numeric_std.vhdl:  function TO_UNSIGNED (ARG : NATURAL; SIZE_RES : UNRESOLVED_UNSIGNED) return UNRESOLVED_UNSIGNED; (But you did make me look. To understand why it would analyze without error.)

then that is likely a clue to the problem. 2**NE - 1 - NF - abs_exp_diff will return  a value that is NE bits long, likely much shorter than the OP expected.

I've added the testbench and file I'm using when simulating. I didn't understand your answers

The function to_unsigned with an unsigned as second parameter (named SIZE_RES) is defined as:
  function TO_UNSIGNED (ARG : NATURAL; SIZE_RES : UNRESOLVED_UNSIGNED)
      return UNRESOLVED_UNSIGNED is
  begin
      return TO_UNSIGNED (ARG  => ARG,
                          SIZE => SIZE_RES'length);
  end function TO_UNSIGNED;

The return value is an unsigned which has the length of the second parameter SIZE_RES.
Your second parameter is "2**NE - 1 -NF - abs_exp_diff".
So the function does not use the value which is calculated by this expression,
but its length, which is determined by the length of abs_exp_diff.
Therefore the first expression of the concatenation gives NE+1 bits.
The second has NF+1 bits.
The third has NE+1 bits again (length of abs_exp_diff).
But mx_p_nt_a has 2*NE+1 bits which differs from NE+1+NF+1+NE+1.

The error is present for ghdl -r fp_sum_subs (ghdl has the ability to simulate while top level ports are unbound and not forced).  Because there are no external events (e.g. clk) that tells you one or more simulation cycles will occur assigning values to signals in non-sequential statements including the assignment to mx_p_nt_a.  You've described the problem analytically per Tricky's comment. How should it be fixed? (and why for which method you choose, this gets into IEEE Std 854/754 territory  as well as the correctness of the question's code lacking a testbench).
